# change default pushpin from BingMapsTask class

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, bing-maps, pushpin

I wonder if it is possible to open the bing map application after button click and send there my own .png icon for push pin. For now I can open the bing maps and I have a default pushpin, but I want to change that pushpin for my own.

This is my code for it:

```
        var bingMapsTask = new BingMapsTask
        {
            SearchTerm = item.CoordinatesString
        };
        bingMapsTask.Show();
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to modify the pushpin when using the Bing Maps Task as that opens up a separate app. If you want to be able to customize the map you will need to use the map SDK in WP.